# Is it mutar to receive ordination from the Universal Life Church?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, heresy, semicha

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Life_Church), the Universal Life Church

> is a religious organization that offers anyone semi-immediate
>   ordination as a ULC minister free of charge. The organization states
>   that anyone can become a minister without having to go through the
>   pre-ordination process required by other religious faiths. The ULC has
>   no traditional doctrine, believing as an organization merely in doing
>   "that which is right"

According to halachah, is one allowed to register for ordination from this church/organization?

Comment: Why do you think this may be prohibited?

Comment: From what I read in your Wikipedia link, possible problems - entering a church for meetings & POSSIBLY performing some of the minister functions suggested such as homosexual marriages (homosexuality is forbidden even for *B'nai Noach, AFAIK.) I don't think there is a problem with officiating a Gentile wedding, otherwise.

Comment: @DanF Why would one be required to enter a church or perform any wedding service that he might object to? I thought they do not impose any beliefs

Comment: I may have incorrectly extended an assumption absed on "The ULC Headquarters holds weekly church services in a historic church building in Modesto" that all meetings are held in a church, as well. The site does not say much about the process to become ordained. Also, why they don't impose beliefs, aren't most baptisms and marriages in a church? Also, perhaps, there is a problem mentioning Jesus's name as part of the service, even if you don't believe in Jesus?

Comment: @DanF Who said anything about Jesus? This has nothing to do with Christianity. There are no requirements to being ordained.

Comment: @DoubleAA I know that. I'm talking about ministering for baptisms which is Christian. Or a Christian-based wedding. In other words, anything ministered would probably have to be "neutral" and not in a church. It looks like an option, but the opportunities seems a bit limited.

Comment: @DanF Or you could just use it to officiate for a Jewish wedding

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would one want to do such a thing?

Comment: @Harel13, the ULC is legally registered as a "religion", but in practice it isn't.  It was originally set up to take advantage of American laws to allow one to avoid the draft (during the Vietnam war) and to avoid property taxes (church property is exempt).  Members are not expected to adhere to any supernatural beliefs. (I was ordained in 1979, something that has had no effect whatsoever on my religious beliefs.)  Despite its name, *The Satanic Temple* is a similar, more recent, non-religious religion, created to oppose laws that favour specific religions.

Comment: @DanF, "church" is the English word for the Greek "ekklesia", which is the usual translation of the Hebrew word "קָהֵל" ("assembly" as in Deut. 9:10).  It simply means people "called out" from the world for a special purpose.  The ULC holds no Christian-specific beliefs (or those of any other religion for that matter).

Comment: @RayButterworth thanks. Tax evasion you say? Interesting... :D

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues that come to mind as potentially halachically problematic"

1. *Marith A'yin* (creating an impression of wrongdoing) by making it seem that you have been ordained by a Christian church (see e.g.
   DanF's objections in the comments to the question) and endorse
   idolatrous/heretical beliefs.
2. *Marith A'yin* that you are engaging in dishonest practices by making use of loopholes in laws designed for religious clergy in
   order to, e.g., take advantage of tax benefits. (This is probably
   the weakest argument since if the law allows it, what makes it a
   dishonest loophole.)
3. Actual association with a heretical cult inasmuch as modern conceptions of ethical pluralism are in sharp contrast with the ethical pluralism espoused by the Torah. *Kol hamodeh ba'avoda zara kofer b'chol hatorah kula* - to acknowledge idolatry is to deny the entire Torah. (In addition, I believe issues have been raised by contemporary poskim regarding joining interdenominational organizations, presumably for similar reasoning.)

A better idea might be to develop an Orthodox Jewish equivalent ordination, perhaps offered automatically at Bar/Bat Mitzva (when the typical Orthodox Jewish boy/girl already know more about halacha than most Reform rabbis). Considering that the Jews are meant in their entirety to be a *mamlecheth kohanim w'goy qadosh* ("a kingdom of priests and consecrated nation"), this actually seems entirely appropriate.

Comment: "*perhaps offered automatically at Bar/Bat Mitzva (when the typical Orthodox Jewish boy/girl already know more about traditional Judaism than most Reform rabbis)*" - Criticize Reform for what it is, not for caricatures.

Comment: re: #3, I think I understand your argument to be that if this is explicitly pluralistic, meaning that no religion has a greater claim on truth than any other, it is implicitly akin to מודה בע"ז, however I don't know that this church endorses such a metaphysical pluralism as opposed to a more pragmatic kind, and regardless, I don't know that receiving ordination from them implies consent to any doctrine inasmuch as they don't appear to have one

Comment: #1 seems like the only strong claim, here. (I admit a bias as I had commented on it.) #2, as you imply, is not Mar'it ayin. You are permitted to use the legalities of tax laws for any reason. If the IRS permits it, it's not illegal, so how can it be *marit ayin*? #3 doesn't seem to follow from the claims of Wikipedia about what the org. does. It states that it does not enforce belief in any specific religion and members include atheists. My brother tour guides Christian Pilgrims visiting Israel and cites the Gospels as part of the tour.  Does the citing alone imply *modeh ba'avoda zara*?

Comment: The Bar Mitzvah idea is theoretically interesting, but counter-productive even w/o your comparison. (BTW, the claim, I think may be false, but in its context it IS stereotypical.) Bar Mitzvah is merely the START of learning and, AFAIK, the youngest person to receive a "rav" status was R Elazar ben Azariah at age 17, IIRC. None of the great sages got it at 13, and these days, I know no one of the stature of R. Elazar or the other sages of that time.

Comment: There is no ma'aris ayin from non-Jews, fwiw.

Comment: @ezra אפילו בחדרי חדרים?